# Is there a way to search data from DataFrame without knowing where the data is located?

Tags: python

I'm reading a workbook file in Excel and converting it into Data frame. I'm trying select certain data in the DataFrame and assign it to a variable.  the thing is the data isn't always in the location as it come in from the excel file. Any suggestions?

```
wb = load_workbook(strTotalFile,data_only = True)       
for sheet in wb.sheetnames:
   ws = wb[sheet]
   data = ws.values

   pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
   df = pd.DataFrame(data)
   location = df.iloc[17,1]  <---The location is the only data that doesn't change.
```

Comment: What does your data look like? You can use pandas for some "clever" indexing rules, but it depends on the data if that is possible in this case. But to be sure, you only need 1 value from your worksheet?

Comment: It's basically 3 check studs on each sheet in the workbook. So the data is everywhere. I need all the data just from one check stub @3DspatialUser on the sheet

Comment: one of the first things I do when ETL-ing an Excel spreadsheet (especially when provided by vendors who are trying to be helpful and decorate their sheets to the max) is to normalize all the data into a skinny, DB-friendly form: `(sheet_no, row, col, value)`. Then, there is often post-processing needed to "find" relevant data (e.g. values in sub-tables all over the spreadsheet).

Comment: @PierreD Can you show me an example?

Comment: Well, if you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (a simple input sample along with the desired output), we may be able to help you further. For example, you could write a function that creates a small spreadsheet that exhibits some of the problems you are facing, as well as what the expected result should be.